# How can I create an auto-delete function for CouchDB in Python

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm new to Python and CouchDB and I'm trying to write an auto-trading script.  As such, I only care about the most recent 400 documents in a given database/table (trading data). To fill in a few blanks:

1. I have one Python program that is reading FOREX trading data and writing summary statistics to a CouchDB database. That thing runs every 20 seconds and works great. I'm just creating some large tables (that I don't need), at this point.
2. I have another Python program that is going to read the top 400 records from that table. At the tail end of this program, I'd like to do some kind of auto-purge that will delete anything older than the top 400 documents.

I have some flexibility in how I do this, as this is just a pet project to learn some new programming technologies. I'm assuming this can be solved with a collection of using *_id = epoch time + views*, but I just want something that is bare-bones easy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As the number of docs ramaining is so small compared to the rest that you want to purge, i would try to do a selective replication to a new database with a post to _replicate and adding the 400 relevant ids in the doc_ids array. (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/common.html#post--_replicate)

Then just swap to the new database and delete the old one. This will be very fast and very error proof, as couchdb just needs to delete the old database and index files instead of finding and deleting thousands of old docs.